# AirPods Proのサイトようなサイトをつくるには

Tags: javascript, html, css

AirPods Proのサイト https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/ のように動画とスクロールバーが連動して動くサイトを作りたいと思っています。

どうしたらいいんでしょうか？

大まかな制作の方法ご存じの方いますか？

Comment: 質問の範囲が広い印象があります、これだとなかなか回答が付きづらいと思います。例えばAir Pod Pro サイトをまず提示していただいて、特定の機能の作り方（たとえばカートや決済など）やUI表現（たとえば無限スクロールやスライドショー）もしくはサーバ構成（大量のアクセスをさばく方法やサーバの構築の仕方）など質問内容を絞っていただくことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

javascriptのオープンソースに、以下のようなものがあります。
この辺を試してみましょう。ただ、少し難易度は高いかもしれません。

http://scrollmagic.io/

ちなみにこの質問の場合、タグはHTML,css,javascriptになるかと思いますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます。グラフィックデザイナーをしていて、ウェブ担当になってしまい、まだ勉強中の身です。制作したい目標物のイメージが出てきたので、一体どうやって制作していったらいいんだろうと、聞いてみました。ご回答いただけてとてもうれしく思います。チャレンジしてみます。

Comment: scrollmagicで検索すると、いくつか使い方が書かれたブログもあるので、そちらも参考にしてみてください！